# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."

Tags: wallet

I'd like to import Mercury module, but some errors occur.
I can't confirm this reason on react version or other things.
Can I solve this error using current react version? If It's impossible, other solution?
Thank you in advance.

```typescript
"dependencies": {
    "@mercury-chat/react-chat": "^0.1.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",    
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5",
     ...
 },

import React from 'react';
import { MercuryChat } from '@mercury-chat/react-chat';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MercuryChat />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Failed to compile.

```javascript
./node_modules/@mercury-chat/react-chat/dist/index.js 509:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (509:5)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
| class EmbeddedWalletAPI {
>   api;
|   wallet;
|   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```